# Is it possible to use the same PostgreSQL database transaction with Knex.js and TypeORM?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, transactions, typeorm, knex.js

Both Knex.js and TypeORM support database transactions with PostgreSQL.

- https://knexjs.org/guide/transactions.html
- https://typeorm.io/transactions

1. **Is it possible to create a PostgreSQL transaction with either Knex.js or TypeORM and use the same transaction with the other db client?**
2. Do *"two-phase commit transactions"*,  *"distributed transactions"* or *"XA transactions"* help in this regard?